# The command Split not working from a List<string> but from a normal string

Tags: c#

.Split(' ').Last()` not working as expected.

I have the following:

```
print("1) " + "Lidingö kommun Sverige".Split(' ').Last());

string xx = "Lidingö kommun Sverige";

print("2) " + xx.Split(' ').Last());

print("3) " + Utility.setup_List[0].freqFullLocationName);

print("4) " + Utility.setup_List[0].freqFullLocationName.Split(' ').Last());
```

The `Utility.setup_List[0].freqFullLocationName` is a string.

I get the following results:

```
1) Sverige
2) Sverige
3) Lidingö kommun Sverige 
4)
```

Given that the `Utility.setup_List[0].freqFullLocationName` is a string I do not understand why it is not split correct. I have tested to first copy to a new string and then split with the same result.

Comment: There is a space after "Sverige"

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. As @NineBerry suggests, there is likely a difference between `xx` and `Utility.setup_List[0].freqFullLocationName` that you are not seeing.

Comment: Probably you want to trim before the split. 
Utility.setup_List[0].freqFullLocationName.Trim().Split(.............)
So this way you are removing Leading and Trailing Space from that string!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of `freqFullLocationName` is "Lidingö kommun Sverige " with a space at the end.

So, `Split()` works as expected because it it recognizes the space and splits "Sverige" from an empty string entry after the following space.

If you want to fix this behavior, you can specify the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option when calling `Split()`. Or use `Trim()` on the string before calling `Split()`.

```
print("4) " + Utility.setup_List[0].freqFullLocationName.
    Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last());
```

Comment: Oh sh.. my fault. I missed that. A BIG thank you all!